# My dog is extremely overweight

Tags: dogs, health, diet, weight

Over the years my dog has been taking on weight. I didn’t notice at first until I was going through some pictures of him when he was at a healthy weight. I am not sure what type of dog he is, but I assume he is mixed with Chihuahua. So my question is, what are some ways I could start to take off the weight without going to the vet? I cannot check him in the vet due to my personal situation right now. Can you give me some ideas of ways to get him back to shape? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to pets! Please take the [tour] and have a look at [what it means if a question is closed as duplicate](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates). I linked you to a similar question that already has several answers. If you have any specific problems with the weight loss of your dog or any other question, please feel free to create a new post.